# iOS - how to count the num of Taps inside a specific view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, multi-touch, touches

I'm trying to evolve from the iOS 4.2 sample "Touches" but I can't do it (I'm new to the iOS):
I'd like to count taps on each of the different UIImageViews. Currently the sample count taps no matter where I press, in the views, outside the UIImageView(s), etc. What I want is to show how many taps I'm tapping inside a specific UIImageView.
The output would be a label saying `7 taps on the red button; 2 taps on the yellow button; 3 taps on the green`.

Comment: Can you detect the taps inside the image or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I got it:

```
NSUInteger touchCount = 0;
for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
    if(numTaps >= 2) {
        CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
        if (CGRectContainsPoint([firstTapView frame], touchPoint)) {
            firstTapView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",numTaps];
        } else if (CGRectContainsPoint([secondTapView frame], touchPoint)) {
            secondTapView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",numTaps];
        } else if (CGRectContainsPoint([thirdTapView frame], touchPoint)) {
            thirdTapView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",numTaps];
        } 

    }

    touchCount++;  
}
```

where firstTapView, secondTapView and thirdTapView are my UILabels, shown on the screen. Touches sample uses UIImageView, but I changed it to UILabel, so I can write whilst touching the screen.